# Geometric representation for Cartesian products of two line segments

Tags: geometry

A part of question 4 in [page 11 of Mathematical Analysis I](https://books.google.com/books?id=rxOoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=geometric%20representation%20for%20direct%20cartesian%20product%20line&source=bl&ots=cbbb8dtuo2&sig=BsKw8wLr2XeCWJ7eQpJkb_vTHmc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT4oDU_dvPAhWEJhoKHaujBfoQ6AEIRDAF) by `Vladimir A. Zorich` ask this in about [`Cartesian product`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product):

> Give geometric representations of ...
>
> a) The Product of two line segments (a rectangle).

If assume each line segment as a set of 2D points, then their `Cartesian product` will be a set which is sitting in $\mathbb R^4$. So how we can create a rectangle? I think it means creating a relation between a 4D thing and 2D one. Probably I have to propose "lines between points of two segments" as elements of `Cartesian product`. But

1. It is not the definition of the set which is the result of `Cartesian product`.
2. Also, by this way, how we can represent a geometrical representation for `Cartesian product` of a line and a point?

Comment: A 2D rectangle in a 4D space. Anything wrong?

Comment: @Vim So elements are not `lines`?

Comment: Elements of the resulting Cartesian product? Of course they aren't lines but points in a 4D space.

Comment: @Vim And what about Cartesian product of a line and a point? Does it has any shape?

Comment: It is again a line. It is a 2D shape itself, but can live in spaces of any dimension, depending on the spaces the line and the point live in.